# cts:values function not returning all the values for path reference

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Let's assume I have three documents in MarkLogic as below,

```
 <employee>
    <name>a</name>
    <age>10</age>
</employee>

<employee>
    <name>b</name>
    <age>10</age>
</employee>

<employee>
    <name>c</name>
    <age>10</age>
</employee>
```

Documents uris - **/employee/a, /employee/b, /employee/c** respectively.
I have created path range index for `"/employee/age"` as `int` scalar stype.

My Requirement is - Get the Sum of all the values of path range index `"/employee/age"`.

**I tried** - `sum(cts:values(cts:path-reference("/employee/age")))` but **it is returning 10 as output sum** here **I am expecting 30 as output sum**.

What will be the solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cts:values()` function returns the list of distinct values present. It returned a single 10 value so your sum was 10.

Try `cts:sum-aggregate()` which is appropriate for this use case and takes frequency into consideration. Docs can be found at http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:sum-aggregate.